# php search by options

Tags: php

Hi guys I'm trying to show result on webpage by PHP options search my code is as below

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$tbl_name="socio";
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
  $input = $_GET['stYear'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM socio where year='$input'";
  $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
    echo $row['socio'];
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

**Error**

> Notice: Undefined index: stYear in C:\Apache24\htdocs on line 9

Comment: `$_GET` or `$_POST`? also you are open to SQL injections. Also if you only need the `socio` column you should only select that column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Hi I'm not sure where to use $_GET or $_POST variable also socio is a table

Comment: Then `$row['socio']` is incorrect, the indices are columns, not the table. Your `$input = $_GET['stYear'];` should be `POST` I'd guess since you are entering the conditional.

Comment: <?php
include 'db.php';
$tbl_name="socio";
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$input = $_POST['stYear'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM socio where year='$input'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
 echo $input;
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
I just changed my code & it shows out only a blank page

Comment: Update the question. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41334942/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't validated your input. Hence the issue.
Validate and sanitize!

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $_POST['stYear'] = array_key_exists('stYear', $_POST) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['stYear']) : null;
    if (empty($_POST['stYear'])) {
        exit('Invalid year given');
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM socio WHERE year ='$input'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo 'You selected '.$input;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Also, if you only intend to use the years you've provided in your form, you can whitelist them by adding `in_array($_POST['stYear'], ['2014-15', '2015-16', '2016-17', '2017-18', '2018-19'])`.
Example below:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $_POST['stYear'] = array_key_exists('stYear', $_POST) && in_array($_POST['stYear'], ['2014-15', '2015-16', '2016-17', '2017-18', '2018-19']) ? $_POST['stYear'] : null;
    if (empty($_POST['stYear'])) {
        exit('Invalid year given');
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM socio WHERE year ='$input'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo 'You selected '.$input;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Hi I added your validation but it says Invalid year given by the way I put my whole code here for your reference

Comment: include 'db.php';
$tbl_name="socio";
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$input = $_POST['stYear'];
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $_POST['stYear'] = array_key_exists('stYear', $_POST) && ctype_digit($_POST['stYear']) ? $_POST['stYear'] : null;
    if(empty($_POST['stYear'])) {
        exit('Invalid year given');
    }
$sql = "SELECT * FROM socio WHERE year ='$input'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
 echo "You selected ".$input;
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
}

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="searchStYear.php"> <select name="stYear" class="form-control">
          <option value="2014-15">2014-15</option>
          <option value="2015-16" class="active">2015-16</option>
          <option value="2016-17">2016-17</option>
          <option value="2017-18">2017-18</option>
          <option value="2018-19">2018-19</option>
         </select><button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
       </form>